# OCR with grouped text based on solid rectangles

Tags: scikit-learn, computer-vision, ocr

I can read text from an image using OCR. However, it works line by line.

I want to now group text based on solid lines surrounding the text.

For example, consider I have below rectangle banners. I can read text line by line. Fine! Now I want to group them by Board A,B,C and hold them in some data structure, so that I can identify, which lines belong to which board. It is given that images would be diagrams like this with solid lines around each block of text.

Please guide me on the right approach.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using EasyOcr with parameter `paragraph=True`.
For further details refer `https://www.jaided.ai/easyocr/documentation/`